# Tests that verify the calling of remove function of the Python os module fail

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, mocking

I am trying to mock Python `os` module but my mocking steps are not working.

The code in the file *os_mock.py*:

```
import os 

class MyTestMock:

    def rm(self):
        # some reason file is always hardcoded
        file_path = "/tmp/file1"
        if os.path.exists(file_path):
            os.remove(file_path)
            print(file_path, 'removed successfully')
        else:
            print(file_path, 'Does not exist')
```

The code in the test case file test_os_mock.py

```
import os
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch
from os_mock import MyTestMock

class TestMyTestMock(unittest.TestCase):
    @patch('os.path')
    @patch('os.remove')
    def test_rm(self, mock_remove, mock_path):
        my_test_mock = MyTestMock()
        mock_path.exists.return_vallue = False
        my_test_mock.rm()
        self.assertFalse(mock_remove.called)

        mock_path.exists.return_vallue = True
        my_test_mock.rm()
        self.assertTrue(mock_remove.called)
```

I am getting below error when I execute test cases

```
F
======================================================================
FAIL: test_rm (__main__.TestMyTestMock)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/unittest/mock.py", line 1336, in patched
    return func(*newargs, **newkeywargs)
  File "/Users/vuser/code/MP-KT/mock/test_os_mock.py", line 15, in test_rm
    self.assertFalse(mock_remove.called)
AssertionError: True is not false

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.008s

FAILED (failures=1)
```

I know I am doing something wrong while mocking, But I could not able to figure it out, I got couple of stack overflow links, I followed it, but no help.

Comment: You have a typo in your code: `return_vallue` instead of `return_value`.

Answer (score 3):

I have made some change only to your test file, while the file `os_mock.py` remains unchanged.

##### Typo: return_vallue --> return_value

If you change `return_vallue` to `return_value` your test passes successfully so these changes (in the 2 points where the errors are present) are sufficient.

In particular the changes are the followings:

- `mock_path.exists.return_vallue=False` --> `mock_path.exists.return_value=False` (*return_vallue* is not correct)
- `mock_path.exists.return_vallue=True` --> `mock_path.exists.return_value=True` (*return_vallue* is not correct)

##### Remove the import os

I have removed the `import os` from the file `test_os_mock.py` because the `patch()` function operates on the script `os_mock.py` and it is not necessary in the test file.
The test works with the import too but it is less clear!

##### Use of `assert_not_called` and `assert_called_once`

In my opinion the package `unittest.mock` provides methods `assert_not_called()` and `assert_called_once()` who can improve your tests.
For example `self.assertTrue(mock_remove.called)` ensures you called the mocked method, instead `mock_remove.assert_called_once()` checks that you called the method exactly one time.

So I recommend the followings changes:

- `self.assertFalse(mock_remove.called)` --> `mock_remove.assert_not_called()`
- `self.assertTrue(mock_remove.called)` --> `mock_remove.assert_called_once()`

##### The new file *test_os_mock.py*

With the changes showed, the file *test_os_mock.py* becomes:

```
#import os    # <--- I remove this import because patch operates on the file os_mock
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch
from os_mock import MyTestMock

class TestMyTestMock(unittest.TestCase):

    @patch('os.path')
    @patch('os.remove')
    def test_rm(self, mock_remove, mock_path):
        my_test_mock = MyTestMock()

        # return_vallue --> return_value
        mock_path.exists.return_value = False
        my_test_mock.rm()
        mock_remove.assert_not_called()
        #self.assertFalse(mock_remove.called)

        # return_vallue --> return_value
        mock_path.exists.return_value = True
        my_test_mock.rm()
        mock_remove.assert_called_once()
        #self.assertTrue(mock_remove.called)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

##### Use of `assert_called_once_with`

In your test case better than `assert_called_once()` is the method `assert_called_once_with()` which verifies the value of the argument passed to the method. With this other method  your test becomes as follow:

```
@patch('os.path')
@patch('os.remove')
def test_rm(self, mock_remove, mock_path):
    my_test_mock = MyTestMock()
    mock_path.exists.return_value = False
    my_test_mock.rm()
    mock_remove.assert_not_called()

    mock_path.exists.return_value = True
    my_test_mock.rm()
    # here is the NEW CHANGE
    mock_remove.assert_called_once_with("/tmp/file1")
```

---

[This link](https://realpython.com/python-mock-library/) is very useful for understanding Mocking object in Python. It explains also the use of `mock.patch()` function.